# Need to check which row has most likes between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to MYSQL!

I need to make a SQL query where i check how many likes a row has (between two tables)

I found another question that looked like mine, but i can't get it to return anything (even though it doesn't create an error.

query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM likes
INNER JOIN (SELECT likes.like_id,
                   COUNT(*) AS likes
              FROM likes
        INNER JOIN uploads ON likes.upload_id=uploads.upload_id
             WHERE uploads.upload_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY)
          GROUP BY uploads.upload_id) x ON x.like_id = likes.like_id
  ORDER BY x.likes DESC
```

Link to the original question:
[MySQL, Need to select rows that has the most frequent values in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222616/mysql-need-to-select-rows-that-has-the-most-frequent-values-in-another-table)

Help is much appreciated

Kind regards,
Mathias

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your table structure I'll have to guess..

```
select someid, count(*) cnt from
(
   select * from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.someid = t2.someid
) as q0 group by someid order by cnt desc;
```

It will need tweaking to fit your schema.

Comment: I'm gonna try this out! Thanks! How would you have me post my database structure?

Comment: Typically people put it in the problem description. You can just do a 'describe table <name>' or 'show create table <name>' and copy that output.

Comment: Just an alias for 'count(*)' so you can use it in the 'order by'

Comment: SELECT uploads.upload_id, count(*) AS cnt from
(
   SELECT * FROM likes JOIN uploads ON likes.uploads_id = uploads.upload_id
) AS q0 GROUP BY likes ORDER BY cnt desc; 

ERROR: #1054 - Unknown column 'likes.uploads_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: you have likes.uploads_id - should it be likes.upload_id (singular)?

Comment: The query halts, it wont return any error or result to me now, unfortunately.